# Chess Construction Challenge #D: 8 moves

Tags: chess, construction

Since I "burnt" [the complete question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35246/another-mobility-puzzle) elsewhere, let's start with "D" (I counted up in hex) and 8 moves. The position in the answer there can be improved by far!
OK, to recapitulate: Legal position, no promoted material, as many pieces as possible, each piece has 8 legal moves, ties broken by proof game length.

Comment: Fancy to see you here! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non symmetric entry with

> 20 pieces.

> [image]

Will add proof game when/if required.

Comment: Nice one. It's a pity that you can almost fit in one more black knight on e3 there.

Comment: @justhalf or on c5 for that matter.

Comment: or on d4 for that matter.

Comment: Great! A shame that Re2 (then +Nc5) doesn't work either. "Uppie" pending, maybe someone does 21.

Comment: Wait, why doesn't it work? Edit: Ah, the white king.

Answer (score 2):

Let's open the challenge (without a proof game, since I already know a solution with more pieces is possible)

> 16 pieces

> [image]

Comment: Nice start, especially as usually the knights kick the kings hard. (Consequently, my current record attempt has none...but I'm confident it can be beaten.)